# Primefaces scrollable datatable header alignment

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, scroll

I know it is often discussed issue but I didn't find any reasonable solution. I have a datatatable with filtering, sorting, lazy loading and dynamic columns. If I set width of a datatable to 100% and scroll to right, cells don't align to a header. Is some simple solution?  I'm using primefaces-5.0.

[image: Datatable screenshot]

XHTML:

```
<p:dataTable 
    var="rec" 
    value="#{bean.list}"
    selection="#{bean.selectedRow}"
    selectionMode="single"
    rowKey="#{rec.id}"
    resizableColumns="true"
    rows="4"
    paginator="true"
    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
    filteredValue="#{bean.filteredList}"
    scrollable="true"
    style="width: 100%;">   

    <p:columns value="#{bean.list}"
       width="150"
       var="column" 
       sortBy="#{rec[column.property]}" 
       filterBy="#{rec[column.property]}" 
       filterMatchMode="contains" >
       <f:facet name="header">
           <h:outputText value="#{column.header}" />
       </f:facet>
       <h:outputText value="#{rec[column.property]}" /> 
    </p:columns>
</p:datatable>
```